# AES Encryption of api string response returning extra characters at start

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt API encrypted response. But the decryption process returning extra characters at the start and also missing a double-quoted characters of JSON format response key shown below:

```
private void setListener() {

        btnDecode.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              decodeCode();
            }
        });

    }

private void decodeCode() {

        String response = "bk/qo1fYH3aKseRNcXq6FLn2ScpSTZDyse4YINiQV34XTb2mOV95sB8uBemWl9p6XSGVYga+K6/n3LyJEgiyAmijL+y/ahb1h0ehv1Ejej+uVWN4yXWUr4TOFz+78iU5A9+znSQXIQIo8ti9Z+ALpvu4lqrDo2hZbF0OKDxxgOjLF28NSrNpVo9eThaH33vFmYZUZ1zFj281g8ahj6wf0MuL0Ev9bsI9AhX4eW0rJZSacW2/xZH81EPxcojerCzGnALxVGlE/MzxLSieUMWRkxKxQZ/Ux6EhiJy6kTkS4iku1Uk/qQJglj22eiIPROpNARts2lOo09PdsgJZb3DKm+j16FKfEC+fpLykXqQ5shtcW/tB0Qer+XFNBHGblDMYBaVzqahunvzHQKaSu2vF+A==";
        try {
         String responseResult =  encryptUtils.decrypt (response, "1234567891123456");
         txtDecode.setText (responseResult);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
}
```

Here in return I am getting some extra characters before actual string. Also the Response key in which the complete response exist has invalid syntax i.e Response key start double-quote is missing. Decrypted string getting is:

```
J`@TBBKE@FQResponse":"{\"access_token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IllhYm5lciIsIm5iZiI6MTU3MjUxNDI2MywiZXhwIjoxNTcyNTE2MDYzLCJpYXQiOjE1NzI1MTQyNjN9.w4cQcr4pT3hyGPW5MOS7QbWL64nvHBf97OJ8DQWDRRg\",\"badge_Id\":\"108817\"}","ResponseMessage":"Login Success"}
```

And this is my EncryptUtils class. In this I have tried NoPadding encryption also in decrypt method but didn't work for me:

```
public class EncryptUtils {

    public String encrypt(String value, String key)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        byte[] value_bytes = value.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] key_bytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        return Base64.encodeToString(encrypt(value_bytes, key_bytes, key_bytes), 0);
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] paramArrayOfByte1, byte[] paramArrayOfByte2, byte[] paramArrayOfByte3)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        // setup AES cipher in CBC mode with PKCS #5 padding
        Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // encrypt
        localCipher.init(1, new SecretKeySpec (paramArrayOfByte2, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec (paramArrayOfByte3));
        return localCipher.doFinal(paramArrayOfByte1);
    }

    public String decrypt(String value, String key)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
    {
        byte[] value_bytes = Base64.decode(value, 0);
        byte[] key_bytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        return new String(decrypt(value_bytes, key_bytes, key_bytes), "UTF-8");
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] ArrayOfByte1, byte[] ArrayOfByte2, byte[] ArrayOfByte3)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        // setup AES cipher in CBC mode with PKCS #5 padding
        Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // decrypt
        localCipher.init(2, new SecretKeySpec(ArrayOfByte2, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(ArrayOfByte3));
        return localCipher.doFinal(ArrayOfByte1);
    }

    private byte[] getKeyBytes(String paramString)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        byte[] arrayOfByte1 = new byte[16];
        byte[] arrayOfByte2 = paramString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.arraycopy(arrayOfByte2, 0, arrayOfByte1, 0, Math.min(arrayOfByte2.length, arrayOfByte1.length));
        return arrayOfByte1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just some observations: 1) Chunks of the code look like output from a Java decompiler rather than original source code. 2) You need to know the encryption specification to be able to write and debug decryption code. 3) Your output strongly suggests that you have the correct key, IV, and mode of AES. In other words, your decryption is correct but you have an incorrect understanding of how the plaintext is structured.

Comment: Another possibility is that you are using an incorrect iv, which in your case is the key bytes, and the difference between the correct IV and the key bytes is low entropy. As your key has low entropy, you might try decrypting with, for example, an IV of 16 0 bytes or some other likely fixed array of 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption that the IV is a copy of the key appears to be incorrect. It appears that the IV is all zeros. You can confirm this by replacing this line in `decrypt`:

```
return new String(decrypt(value_bytes, key_bytes, key_bytes), "UTF-8");
```

with

```
return new String(decrypt(value_bytes, key_bytes, new byte[16]), "UTF-8");
```

The decryption result becomes
`{"Status":true,"Response":"{\"access_token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IllhYm5lciIsIm5iZiI6MTU3MjUxNDI2MywiZXhwIjoxNTcyNTE2MDYzLCJpYXQiOjE1NzI1MTQyNjN9.w4cQcr4pT3hyGPW5MOS7QbWL64nvHBf97OJ8DQWDRRg\",\"badge_Id\":\"108817\"}","ResponseMessage":"Login Success"}`